# Simple question about animation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, visualization

There is a simple code to draw lines according some simple rules.

it works but I want to *animate* it by changing one parameter `theta_time`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation

List_1 = [6,4,2,1]
List_2 = [0,0,0,0]
List_3 = [6,4,3,2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

C_x = 0
C_y = 0
cx = [0]
cy = [0]

theta_time = 1  #I want to update this value from 0 to 10

for freq,amp,phase in zip(List_3,List_1, List_2):

    C_x += amp*np.cos(freq * theta_time + np.deg2rad(phase))
    C_y += amp*np.sin(freq * theta_time + np.deg2rad(phase))
    cx.append(C_x)
    cy.append(C_y)

plt.scatter(cx,cy)
plt.plot(cx, cy, '.r-',linewidth=1)    
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to add following code to animate but it doesn't works

```
def animations(theta_time):
    for freq,amp, phase in zip(List_3,List_1, List_2):

    C_x += amp*np.cos(freq * theta_time + np.deg2rad(phase))
    C_y += amp*np.sin(freq * theta_time + np.deg2rad(phase))
    cx.append(C_x)
    cy.append(C_y)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
   fig, animations,frames=np.arange(0,1,0.01),interval=10, blit=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move all computation and plotting lines within `animation` function. The first thing to do in this function is to erase previous plot with `ax.cla()` (otherwise new frames will overlap previous ones). I suggest to add `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim` within `animation` in order to fix axis limits in each frame and avoid unpleasant axis re-sizing from frame to frame. I also added a title with the current `theta_time` value, you can remove it if you want.

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


List_1 = [6,4,2,1]
List_2 = [0,0,0,0]
List_3 = [6,4,3,2]


def animate(theta_time):

    ax.cla()

    C_x = 0
    C_y = 0
    cx = [0]
    cy = [0]

    for freq,amp,phase in zip(List_3,List_1, List_2):

        C_x += amp*np.cos(freq * theta_time + np.deg2rad(phase))
        C_y += amp*np.sin(freq * theta_time + np.deg2rad(phase))
        cx.append(C_x)
        cy.append(C_y)

    ax.scatter(cx,cy)
    ax.plot(cx, cy, '.r-',linewidth=1)

    ax.set_xlim(-15, 15)
    ax.set_ylim(-15, 15)
    ax.set_title(r'$\theta_{time} = $' + str(theta_time))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5, 5))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = animate, interval = 500, frames = 10)

plt.show()
```

[image]